# How to have different minlengths with jquery combobox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have 2 html select menus in html.

I have jqueryui making it into a combobox.

How do I set one to have a different minlength to the default that is set in the plugin?

Answer (score -1):

You can use different selectors to target them separately and run `.combobox()` with different `minLength`.

For example, if you have the following HTML:

```
<select id="first">
  <!-- options... -->
</select>

<select id="second">
  <!-- options... -->
</select>
```

You could do something like:

```
$('#first').combobox();  /* first combo box, default minLength */
$('#second').combobox({ minLength: 4 });  /* second , different minLength */
```

You can also change the options after `combobox()` has been called. For example:

```
$('select').combobox();  /* convert all select menus to combobox */
$('#second').combobox("option", "minLength", 0); /* diff minLength for #second */
```

Comment: The select makes all my selects into comboboxes. Nice, never knew i could do that but unfortuanatly I am still unable to change the minlength. This is my code `$(function() {
  $('select').combobox();
  $('#tracklisting').combobox("option", "minLength", 0);
  });` I've tried autocomplete aswell as thats what jqueryui documentation has and it just won't change from the default. The plugin code is exactly the same as the demo on jquery's site